# Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/..../Myapp.app. Swift 4.2 Xcode 10 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently using Xcode 10 beta 6 and my iPhone 10 currently runs iOS 12 public beta 10. (They are both latest version of Xcode 10 and iOS 12 public beta and there should not be compatibility issues coming from using Xcode and iOS versions released in different times)

1) Went to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme then Options and unchecked "Launch due to a background fetch event". Still same problem.

2) "Debug Executable" is unchecked in "Info" section of Edit Scheme. Still same problem.

3) Went to Target -> Capabilities -> Background Modes and then enabled Background Modes by turning it on but did not check "Background fetch". (Should I check that "Background fetch"?) Still same problem.

I have looked around Stackoverflow.com and Google search results for an answer and found three answers that askers claimed to be a working one. But none of them worked for me. And I can assure you that I am using a Developer Certification not a Distributing Certification. Please provide me with some new insights and feel free to ask me questions if it will help troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Are you launching the app under the a simulator or device? Is the app transfered and installed on the device?

Comment: on a device. App is installed and even attempted to open it but it immediately shut down

Comment: Is it a new app or an app which exists and is tested under iOS12? Is the app launching correctly under a simulator? What shows the debuger when the app launching and crashing?

Comment: what was the answer you found

Comment: @JamesRyu could you please share your answer? Having the same problem here.